# Minimising information to guess all hats correctly

Tags: puzzle-creation, hat-guessing

There is a well known [N logicians wearing hats of N colors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70/n-logicians-wearing-hats-of-n-colors) puzzle:

> 1. N logicians are wearing hats with numbers from 1 to N (each hat has one number; there can be multiple hats with the same number). Each logician can see the numbers on all hats except his own.
> 2. The logicians must simultaneously guess a number on their hat.
> 3. They win if **at least one** logician guesses correctly.
> 4. How to do it if they can agree on a strategy beforehand?

Now let's say we want all of the participants to guess correctly. In order to do that we allow them to exchange information before guessing:

> 1. N logicians are wearing hats with numbers from 1 to M (each hat has one number; there can be multiple hats with the same number). Each logician can see the numbers on all hats except his own.
> 2. A. The logicians must simultaneously chose a number, which must be 0, 1, 2 or 3. And then call it out.
>      B. Then, knowing who said what, logicians must simultaneously guess a number on their hat. And call it out.
> 3. They win if **all** logicians guess correctly.
> 4. How to do it if they can agree on a strategy beforehand?

Each logician here gives 2 bits of information to others and you can solve this puzzle for $M$ up to $4^{N-1}$. You can reduce $M_{max}$ to $2^{N-1}$ easily, by making constraint at step 2.A. stronger and allowing them to call out only 0 or 1.

I wonder, **can you make $M_{max}$ smaller than $2^{N-1}$ with even stronger constraints?** Like "2.A. Each one calls out either 0 or 1, but total sum of numbers should be always equal to N/2, or you lose".
 Meanwhile, of course, the solution still should be possible and all logicians must obey the same rules.

**What is the smallest $M_{max}$ here?**

Comment: How can such constraints like "the total sum of numbers should be always equal to $\frac{N}{2}$" be followed by the logicians, if they have to simultaneously choose a number?

Comment: @A.P. that's the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

> Of course, you can always reduce the information throughput of the logicians by forbidding them more and more things. The smallest $M_{max}$ that you can reach is $1$. Just enable no one to convey any information, and the only case they can guess right is if all hats are the same color.